# Unable to run query for a particular record

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a query in mysql workbench. But it continue running without an end and finally throwing a `1205` error.Most interesting thing is I can update the same field of another record having `statusID=5`.

```
update `catalog`.`order_status` 
set `Status` = 'CONFIRMED' 
where `StatusID` = '4'
```

Comment: you can restart your workbench and please remove single quote from where clause StatusID value like `StatusID` = 4. This could work

Comment: Do you use `MyISSAM` or `InnoDB` engine? There can be problem with key_buffer_size, memory, concurrency, table locks etc.

Answer (score 0):

1205 indicates 'lock wait timeout'. You are trying to update a record that is probaby locked. It can be locked whilst updating lots of records/then hitting a timeout error of say, 300 seconds (depending on your configuration of the application you're using to fire off your queries.)

fix 1: figure out the actual issue:
 run (in MySQL) 
`show full processlist;`
 and identify what query is running and locking the one/some of the rows.
 then 
  `kill query <process id>;`

also you can check your table's ENGINE - InnoDB allows record locking, MyISAM wil lock the whole table (recommend: InnoDB)

fix 2: easy win if the above doesn't work: restart the mysql service. this will release all locks.

option 3: index the StatusID field for quicker searching using 'where' clause; but this is unlikely to be the issue.